# Android: Attribute 'rippleColor' has already been defined

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My Android application had no problems with this build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.marshall.opensurvey"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'

    // Material Drawer Library by Mike Penz
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.3.9@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    // Android Iconics Library by Mike Penz
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:1.7.9@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:1.2.0.1@aar'
    // Google Analytics Library
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    // Circle Image View Library
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    // Flat Button Library
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    // Process Button Library
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.4'
    // Fancy Button Library
    compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.5@aar'

    // Card View and Recycler View Library
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

But, as I added another dependency in the build.gradle file and synced, it started to show an error, saying that the attribute 'rippleColor' has already been defined. The new dependency I put in the gradle file is this.

```
// Material Design Library
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
```

I assume that this error is shown because the newly added one contains an attribute which has the same name that is already defined in the previously added libraries. What should I modify in this file so that the third-party libraries do not crash each other?

Comment: if you already using the latest support library do you really need the another MaterialDesign library?

Comment: @codeskraps Because in the another library there is a UI I would like to use..

Comment: The think is I don't think there's anything you can do in the build.gradle file to about this. Do not use the library or if the UI element is small you could manually add it to you project by importing just the classes and xml attributes you need

Comment: Your issue is here: https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/blob/master/MaterialDesignLibrary/MaterialDesign/src/main/res/values/attributes.xml#L7

Open an issue on the github page if you want to use it with the support libraries.

Comment: Here the issue open on the library:
https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/issues/317

Comment: This is why libraries should prefix their attributes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the [MaterialDesign](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/) library does not prefix its attributes.

The attributes are defined in the `attrs.xml` and you will have to rename the `rippleColor` attribute to something else. 
A good advice here is to prefix all attributes specific to this library, so those won't conflict with other libs.

So it will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomAttributes">
        <!-- Color of ripple animation -->
        <attr name="mdl_rippleColor" format="color|reference" />
        <!-- You can also prefix all other attributes -->
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Afterwards you will have to find all occurrences of this in the code of the [MaterialDesign](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/) Library and prefix them too so those attributes can be read programmatically. One is in the [LayoutRipple (Line: 56)](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/blob/master/MaterialDesignLibrary/MaterialDesign/src/main/java/com/gc/materialdesign/views/LayoutRipple.java#L56) class.

It also seems as this library isn't actively maintained anymore. Circa 200 open issues, and 30 pull requests.

---

To simplify everything for you i've modified and fixed the source (i have also updated to the latest v23.1.0 support library) and uploaded it to the SNAPSHOT maven central repository. You can use it by doing the following 2 steps:

**Add the SNAPSHOT maven repository to your root build.gradle**

```
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
```

As shown here: [SNAPSHOT maven repository](https://github.com/mikepenz/wallsplash-android/blob/master/build.gradle#L15)

**Add the dependency to your build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.mikepenz.thirdparty:material-design-library:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

[Here's the link to the SNAPSHOT *.aar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/mikepenz/thirdparty/material-design-library/).
The maven group is different as i am not allowed to host it with the original maven group.

Comment: I used your lib. App compiled successfully but the problem is I couldn't use `setText()` method of 'ButtonRectangle'. Application was always crashed. However, by changing that class to normal `Button` the method was working fine. Seems something is wrong by the lib. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error. Please check for

```
<attr name="rippleColor" format="color" />
```

in your attrs.xml file in values folder. Refactor this "rippleColor" value so that it does not affect your current use of this name.  Then in your gradle file:

```
 compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4+'
```

This issue should get fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it solved but I found a different solution . It is solved by **niwinnm** 
Cause of the problem com.android.support:design so you should change **com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar** this one to **'com.github.vajro:MaterialDesignLibrary:1.6'**

[enter for solution](https://github.com/vajro/MaterialDesignLibrary)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line of code in build.gradle

compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'

If this exists in your project it can help out.